# Excel VBA: Checking to make sure all controls aren't empty

Tags: vba, excel

In my program, I have a snippet of code in a userfrom that looks at its own controls and loops through to see if all of them are empty. This is for the purpose of using all of the non-null controls' values as search parameters. They are three list boxes and three combo boxes. If it finds a control that is not empty, it sects the function to false and exits. This is because my search found a criteria it can use. I have it setup thus:

```
Function IsAllEmpty() As Boolean
'presumes true until we find evidence of a control being not empty
IsAllEmpty = True
'function elsewhere that sets my control background to normal
ClearControlFormatting
Dim ctrl As Control
'checks every control in the form
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    'that is tagged with "searchme" (there are 6, three listbox, three combobox)
    If ctrl.Tag = "SEARCHME" Then
        'if the value of the control isn't null or len = 0
        If Not IsNull(ctrl) Or Len(ctrl) <> 0 Then
            ctrl.BackColor = vbGreen
            IsAllEmpty = False 'in my other code, I can continue the search if this is triggered
            MsgBox "Everything is good (no sarcasm) on this control!"
            Exit Function
        Else: MsgBox "EVERYTHING IS EMPTY, CARL. THAT KILLS PEOPLE."
        End If
    End If
Next
'If something is empty, tell the user to correct it
If IsAllEmpty = True Then
    MsgBox "YOU NEED TO FILL OUT YOUR SEARCH, PAUL."
End If

End Function
```

I have tried various things to get this to work:

- nesting the Not IsNull(ctrl) statement the only one in the if, the If Len(ctrl) <> 0 part (IDK WHY)
- Removing the Len(ctrl) <> 0 part
- Editing both parts of the Or statement to evaluate for ctrl.Value = "" instead
- Removed the "SEARCHME" tags from the comboboxes, in case their dynamic values were interfering.

However, every time, I have watched this function highlight all of my controls green, and then proceed to continue attempting a search. (The function call down in the search says if all the cells come back null, exit the sub).

I'm at a loss, and would greatly appreciate the help! Thanks!

P.S.: If it helps, the above code is a modified version of the following, meant to check to see if any empty controls exist at all. When I used this on my controls, it found them all to be empty and worked like designed.

```
Function CheckForEmpty() As Boolean
CheckForEmpty = True
ClearControlFormatting

Dim ctrl As Control
'Checks each control that needs to be filled for null or 0 length value
'For every one it finds, it marks red
CheckForEmpty = True

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If ctrl.Tag = "FILL" Then
        If IsNull(ctrl) Or Len(ctrl) = 0 Then
            ctrl.BackColor = vbRed
            CheckForEmpty = False
        End If
    End If
Next
'If something is empty, tell the user to correct it
If CheckForEmpty = False Then
    MsgBox "Please fill out red boxes!"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Just to check. You're trying to get the controls that aren't empty and it is returning all of them?

Comment: `IsNull(ctrl)` returns False whether the control is populated or not. Remove this from your `if` statement and it should work

Comment: @Tom I'm trying to just test if the controls are all empty, if they aren't all empty (and at least one or more are populated), then the program should continue on. If they are empty, exit the function/sub and inform user.
Thank you! Removing IsNull(ctrl) worked! Can you tell me why it didn't mess up my second program? If the Not IsNull(ctrl) messed me, why didn't it constantly throw false and mess me up on the second code?

Answer (score -1):

In this line, change to be explicit that you're looking for the value:

`If Not IsNull(ctrl) Or Len(ctrl) <> 0 Then`

change to:

`If (Not IsNull(ctrl.Value)) OR (Len(ctl.Value & "") <> 0) Then`

First, I added the .Value qualifier to the control.  This is the default property, but sometimes (when assigning to a variant or checking null, for example), it might be checking that the Control itself is null because VBA isn't always smart enough to read your thoughts and you're technically telling it to check the control, and not it's value: be explicit.

Second, I explicitly split the two checks into two separate checks using parentheses.  Not sure it's strictly required, but best to be clear and far easier to read and now we don't have to worry about the fact that it maybe was reading the boolean logic incorrectly.

Third, I added a ZLS concatenation to .Value to force it to ZLS if null before checking the length (you get an 'Invalid Use of Null' error if trying to check the Len() of a null value).

As Tom mentions, in this case ctrl will never be null (as it's part of the form's collection, which won't have null references in it), so the whole thing can be simplified to:

`If Len(ctrl.Value & "") <> 0 Then 'ctrl has no value entered`

Lastly, wrap it up in a `Trim()` function just in case there's a single (or double, or more) space in there, and you have:

`If Len(Trim(ctrl.Value & "")) <> 0 Then 'ctrl has no meaningful value entered`

Comment: `Nz` is an Access function not an Excel function. For me this doesn't work - it still returns all of the controls

Comment: All these years I thought Nz() was part of the VBA library.  Answer edited accordingly.